# Layered navigation filter by attribute - NOT in layered menu

Tags: layered-navigation, filter, category-products

Layered navigation filter by attribute not in layered menu

Is it possible to filter by an attribute in the url like `?myfilter=1` which is not in the left filter menu? So `Use In Layered Navigation` is NO.

help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Layered navigation uses pre-generated indexes to do filtering, so answer is NO, you can not use layered navigation to filter by any attribute.

However, you can add your own filter block, it will adjust product collection based on your own criteria, similar to

`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\Filter\Category.php`

and

`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.php`